# Error when printing random line from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, text-files

I need to print a random line from the file "Long films".

My code is:

```
import random
with open('Long films') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

But it prints this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 3, in <module>
    lines = f.readlines()
line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What do I need to do in order to avoid this error?

Comment: This working fine: https://repl.it/GbiR/15

Comment: no for me, but does now, using - with open('Long films', encoding='latin-1') as f:

Comment: Please put `print(f)` at the start of that `with` block, before `lines = f.readlines()`. It should print the representation of the file handle object, and that will tell us the encoding the file was opened with. I suspect that it's not UTF-8, like it ought to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with printing, it is with reading. It seems your file has some special characters. Try opening your file with a different encoding:

```
with open('Long films', encoding='latin-1') as f:
   ...
```

Also, have you made any settings to your locale? Have you set any encoding scheme at the top of your file? Ordinarily, python3 will "helpfully" decode your text to `utf-8`, so you typically should not be getting this error.

Comment: There's something funny with the OP's setup. Consider: why is Python trying to decode the file as 'ascii' rather than as 'UTF-8'?

Comment: @PM2Ring An issue with OP's locale settings maybe? Ordinarily python would decode to utf-8, am I correct?

Comment: Maybe. Yes, the default encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, since the OP has accepted your answer I guess the file is actually encoded with Latin-1 (aka ISO 8859-1). But I'm still a little puzzled by that 'ascii' error message. When I open a Latin-1 file with the default UTF-8 encoding I get a message like `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 128: invalid start byte`

Comment: @PM2Ring It's possible OP was overriding the default utf-8 coding with something else.